# Always using the same OAUTH code with Dropbox-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the [official Dropbox JS library](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) in a Node.js server. It only ever needs to authenticate as a single user, and it can't go through the whole OAUTH browser setup every time the server starts. I am attempting to write an auth driver that pretends to be like the `NodeServer` driver, but runs the callback straight away with a code that always stays the same.

Here's what I've got (it's coffeescript, but you get the idea):

```
myAuthDriver = {
    authType: -> return "code"
    url: -> return "http://localhost:8912/oauth_callback" # What the url would be if I were using NodeServer
    doAuthorize: (authUrl_s, stateParam, client, callback) ->
        authUrl = url.parse(authUrl_s, true)

        callback({
            code: "[a code I just got using the NodeServer driver]"
            state: authUrl.query.state
        })
}
```

Running `authenticate` with this driver set causes this error:

```
Dropbox OAuth error invalid_grant :: given "code" is not valid
```

The docs say that this should only occur with a broken auth driver (but it doesn't give any ideas for fixing it).

Does anyone with more knowledge of OAUTH or Dropbox know what's wrong here?

**Note:** I've found in several places online that Dropbox OAUTH codes never expire

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this question is (as of today) almost 5 years old and that the Dropbox JS repo linked above was deprecated and substituted by a new one -> https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have an OAuth 2 access token, you can just do `var client = new Dropbox.Client({token: '<your token>'});`. No need for an auth driver at all.

(If you want an easy way to get an access token, consider using https://dbxoauth2.site44.com.)